# I am new to angular and I want to load the nested component to the module with one component default. Is it possible to create this in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

My application structure is as follow:

```
-app
 -Home(module)
   -index(component)
     -index.component.html
     -....
   -home-routing.module.ts
   -home.component.html
   -home.component.scss
   -home.component.spec.ts
   -home.component.ts
   -home.module.ts
   
 -Shared(Module)
  -components
   -headercomponent ...
   -footercomponent...
```

I have assigned default address as '' in routing to route home/index component by default. But the informations of home.component.html (from home module) are not displayed. I want to render components of home along with its information.
[By routing to index it only renders the information from index component i.e. home module information is not displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8l40.png)

[I want output like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcyRi.png)
How is it possible?

Sample : https://github.com/sundaracharya/astrohimalaya.git

Comment: Sundar, can you create a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ ? I'll take it from there . Without much info of code, this question will be closed soon. Hurry up!

Comment: I have posted a sample in git repository. Please view in there. https://github.com/sundaracharya/astrohimalaya.git

Comment: Hello Shashank, Got anything?

Comment: let me know if azeem's answer worked. From a quick look, you need to put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` . I didnt get time to download and install the git project. Thats why the stackblitz demo attracts quick answer. Do let me know if Azeem helped, or I'll try to clone your repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no identifier for index component to render the home component's content you have to use the Home component either  as a selector inside the index component or use a router outlet and route manually from ts file by injecting Router.

Comment: I am having trouble on rendering index or any other(dynamic component as redirected from header component). The result I am receiving is the single component redirects. I want to render like <router-outlet> renders the components.

Comment: your index.html doesn't have the any placeholder or router-outlet so that routing can happen add router-outlet inside the index.html...

Comment: Finally, I got it. Thank you azeem for your suggestion. I was unable to render because I was not routing as children and also the router-outlet.